# iReport 4.5.1: “Stretch With Overflow” a single word

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a text field with option ***Stretch With Overflow***. It works perfect except when I have long word in my text. In that case the part of my ‘long’ word is hidden.

How can I force to stretch a single word in two lines?